# Joining two tables and creating PIVOT for varchar with boolean value in SQL

Tags: sql-server-2008, join, pivot-table

Working with `SQL Server 2008` tables where A user can have one or multiple roles

**UserDetails**:

```
 username  level       country      role
 =============================================
  john        A          USA      SystemAdmin
  john        B          Brazil   Co-ordinator
  Smith       G          Spain      Doctor
  Anne        D          USA        Nurse
  ....        ...        ....       ....
```

**RoleDetails**:

```
 role            function
 ============================
  SystemAdmin      full time    
  Doctor           part time    
  Co-ordinator     consultant    
  Nurse            On call    
  ....        ...
```

I am trying to create a VIEW where data would look like

```
 username  level       country   SystemAdmin     Co-ordinator    Doctor  Nurse
 =============================================================================
  john        A          USA          1              0             0       0
  john        B          Brazil       0              1             0       0
  Smith       G          Spain        0              0             1       0
  Anne        D          USA          0              0             0       1
  ....        ...        ....       ....             ....          ....   ...
```

What I am trying to do is join two tables and generate columns from the rows of the second table where both of them are joined on the basis of `UserDetails.role = RoleDetails.role`. And most of the columns are `varchar` in the database. I am trying to generate the Columns from `RoleDetails` rows with boolean value dynamically. Since `RoleDetails` table will continue growing, I could not select the individual row like `PIVOT ( MAX(role) FOR role IN (Doctor, Nurse...))`

Not sure if this is feasible or how to do it. Any direction would be appreciated.

Comment: How is the view going to be used?

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question and here is the typical way to do this. If you need to handle the list of roles dynamically then you'll find many solutions out there using dynamic SQL along with XML features to accomplish string concatenation when building the column list.

```
select
    u.username,
    min(u.level) as level,
    min(u.country) as country,
    min(case when role = 'SystemAdmin'  then 1 else 0 end) as SystemAdmin,
    min(case when role = 'Co-ordinator' then 1 else 0 end) as "Co-ordinator",
    min(case when role = 'Doctor'       then 1 else 0 end) as Doctor,
    min(case when role = 'Nurse'        then 1 else 0 end) as Nurse
from UserDetails u left outer join RoleDetails r
    on r.role = u.role
group by u.username
```

Your application may be able to get away with something like this if you can part a hard limit on the number of roles. Depending on how you intend to use this it may be preferable to have static column names anyway.

```
with NumberedRoles as (
    select rolename, row_number() over (order by role) as rn
    from RoleDetails
)
select
    u.username,
    min(u.level) as level,
    min(u.country) as country,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then 1        else 0 end)    as RoleIsMember01,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then r."role" else null end) as RoleName01,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then 1        else 0 end)    as RoleIsMember02,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then r."role" else null end) as RoleName02,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then 1        else 0 end)    as RoleIsMember03,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then r."role" else null end) as RoleName03,
    ...
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then 1        else 0 end)    as RoleIsMember32,
    min(case when r.rn = 1 then r."role" else null end) as RoleName32
from
    UserDetails u inner join
    NumberedRoles r
        on r."role" = u."role"
group by u.username
```

Comment: In this way I have to list all the roles from the RoleDetails table. If a new row is added to the RoleDetaisl table I woudl have to alter the VIEW again. Is this the only way? Or is there any other better solution?